# best way to upload a large file to wordpress using wp all import

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, import, csv

i am trying to import a csv file that has 50,000 entries to woo commerce. i am using wp all import plugin. now i know there are certain criteria that can be met to speed up the process however having done some further research into this i can see that because of images it can slow down the process quite drastically. i have seen that word press creates multiple sizes of that image when processing the csv. how can this be avoided? i only require the main image which will be used as the thumbnail for the product and for the main image on the product page. each product will only have 1 image. i have seen that using a cdn can speed this up however how do i go about doing this. also is better to split the file up into smaller csv to make the import run successfully? if so what is optimum amount of lines i should have per csv?

Comment: When you say "make the import run successfully" is it actually failing? From the rest of the question it just sounds like it's slow.

Comment: And when you say main image and thumbnail you mean you do need WordPress to do some image resizing to create those images, just not all of the extra images?

Comment: You can use [one of the approaches here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/126718/3276) to turn off or restrict image resizing. Once you have everything imported you can always re-enable some sizes and use wp cli or one of the regenerate thumbnails plugins to process the image sizes you've enabled again.

Comment: i have managed to run imports successfully on a test csv file. it had 35 rows and 50 columns. now this literally took me maybe 3 minutes to run it as i had disabled the do_action and had selected high speed small file processing. now my csv i have watered it down from 100,000 rows to 59,000 rows and 40 columns. what is the best way to go around uploading this csv file? is it best to split it to smaller csv files? if so what is best amount of rows? i have a vps host with 4Vcores, 8gb ram and 160gb ssd. what is the best way to upload this csv file.

Comment: I guess if you want to split it then I'd split it by rows, but I still don't understand why you need to - this is a manageable amount of data. Unless you have a very clever import plugin that runs the import as a sequence of background jobs you probably want to be importing using a command-line tool to import everything, but I don't know what that is - it might end up being simpler to make one. For each record you should only be writing a few rows to the database and ideally copying not uploading the image to the right place: it should be possible to turn off image resizes until later.

Comment: But this isn't anything I've ever had to do myself, and I don't know what tools to recommend. It might be simpler to write something yourself if you can't find anything suitable.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I missed that you were using WP All Import. If you've paid them for support, they ought to help you with this, and it ought to work efficiently. Here's their [slow imports troubleshooting page](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/troubleshooting/slow-imports/). I still think you should try turning off alternative image sizes and instead generate them later.